# Android Development: Layers and Canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble figuring out on how to center these photos or change their initial location. Here is a photo of what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4AGj.jpg

Here is the site I got the code from http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

The source code is at the bottom of the site and can be opened in Eclipse easily.

I am doing this to understand the principles of dragging views and objects and I have that down, it is just I am not too familiar how layers work.

All I need to figure out is how to establish a initial starting point of the objects and not clutter them in one spot.

Answer (score 1):

You should first read [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) to understand the basics of Android Drag and drop.
Here's  another [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) which gives overview of drag process and how events are fired back and forth.

Another [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality--mobile-14402) that may be of your interest